# react setState change hour using moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have a problem setting hour in moment.js, the state seem need a bit of delay to resolve the time before it can change the state.

My event handler look like this

```
handleKeyDownPickerInput(e, type) {
    let input = e.target.value;

      if (!input || isNaN(input)) return;

      if (type === "hour") {
        this.setState({
          currentTime: moment(this.state.currentTime).set({ h: input })
        });
      }
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/w22m3wnj4l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState({
    currentTime: moment(this.state.currentTime).set({ h: input })
});
```

setState method runs asyncronosly so that you can't rely on 'this.state' as it may not read the current state.

```
this.setState((previousState) => ({
        currentTime: moment(previousState.currentTime).set({ h: input })
    })
);
```

Note that setState method takes anonymous function as 1st argument, which you can read the very previous state.

This is the way you are supposed to write.

FYI: 
[State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: another way is just to change to onChange instead of keyDown